# The Change to Pants for Jewish Men

Tags: history, clothing, secular-culture

At what point in history did Jewish men begin wearing pants; what the culture around them was wearing?

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Viola. 

Please consider [registering](//judaism.stackexchange.com/users/signup-unregistered) your account, to [enable](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) more site features, including voting.

Hope to see you around!

Comment: I don't understand the second part of your question. Are you asking what was the mode of dress of non-Jews where Jews were living? This is too broad and out of scope since Jews lived in so many places around the world. Or are you asking what was the first record of Jewish men wearing pants? This might also be out of scope as it relates to Jews, not to Judaism. Please edit to clarify.

Comment: It may relate primarily to Jews, but there is a definite question re Judaism as well. Nowadays, there is a distinction between male and female dress that may not have existed in the past until men adopted wearing trousers. Since there is a prohibition on cross-dressing, this can relate to a halachic aspect and not just a social aspect.